# Bluemix IDS Pipeline build hangs on bower install

Tags: ibm-cloud

I created a shell script build with the IDS Pipeline.

The last line doesn't seem to return for a long time (34 minutes once, 51 minutes before that).

The command is: `bower install`

It runs in < 1 minute locally. And I can see it run fast in the IDS pipeline build output too (command output is printed). It just doesn't exit for a long time.
Any clues how to debug what's going on?
Thank you, Dan

Comment: can you please try again to see if the issue went away?

Comment: Do you have installed bower by using this command : ```npm -g install bower``` ?